# typescript tsc exclude with cmd line args

Tags: typescript, command-line-interface, tsc

I'm working through a tool which need setup compilation dynamically. In that case, we need to maintain a tsconfig json object in a database.

While we use it to compile on certain machine there is a file's writting action. I mean we need to fetch the tsconfig data and write it into a `tsconfig.json` file, then start to tsc compile.

Well, it seems unnecessary to write this config file in the whole process, so I'm seeking for a way to generate a tsc command line from tsconfig json.

From the office [document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), I found it's easy to transform `compilerOptions` to CLI arguments, but have no idea about how to deal with `exclude`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

With the case above, I'v tried some like:

```sh
tsc src/apis/**/*  \
    "\!node_modules" \        # this didn't work
    "\!**/*.spec.ts" \        # this didn't work
    --module "system" \
    --noImplicitAny true \
    --removeComments true \
    --preserveConstEnums true \
    --outFile "../../built/local/tsc.js" \
    --sourceMap true
```

That didn't work, I need some suggestion about how tsc deal with the `exclude` case. Thank for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

I'v got a workaround, it's, to mix up `tsconfig.files`, `tsconfig.include` and `tsconfig.exlude` into an array, then [globby](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globby) it, So that we can manually get the list of files to be flatten to CLI arguments.